# Why does XmlDocument have a namespace that is not declared anywhere (AFAIK)?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, namespaces, xsd

Question:

I'm working with System.Xml.XmlDocument and XPath queries, to extract information from a Microsoft Reporting Services Report.

I have the below two XML files.

If I want to check whether the second file has an (geoname) entry with name attribute = London, I can use this XPath Query:

```
/geonames/geoname[1]/name[text()="London"]
```

On the other hand, if I want to check whether the report has a ReportParameter called in_sprache, I would expect that I could use this XPath query:

```
/Report/ReportParameters/ReportParameter[@Name="in_sprache"]
```

However, that doesn't work. 
So I checked using XMLQuire to get the desired XPath, and it told me the same for geoname, but for the Report, it told me that the XPath is this:

```
/dft:Report/dft:ReportParameters/dft:ReportParameter[@Name="in_sprache"]
```

Now XMLQuire is right, this XPath does work (after declaring dft in the namespace manager).

However, what I don't understand is why mine doesn't work ???

From what I can see, there is no namespace dft (=default ???) defined anywhere.
Yet XMLQuire finds it, so it must be somewhere. 
So why is it the report has (requires) a dft namespace, while the second has none ?
I only see a rd namespace declared...

Microsoft Reporting Service Report:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
<DataSources>
<DataSource Name="COR_Basic">
<rd:DataSourceID>addde073-f37c-4b59-ae3a-25231ffc0ec6</rd:DataSourceID>
<DataSourceReference>COR_Basic</DataSourceReference>
</DataSource>
</DataSources>
<InteractiveHeight>29.7cm</InteractiveHeight>
<ReportParameters>
<ReportParameter Name="in_mandant">
<DataType>String</DataType>
<DefaultValue>
<Values>
<Value>0</Value>
</Values>
</DefaultValue>
<Prompt>Mandant</Prompt>
<Hidden>true</Hidden>
</ReportParameter>
<ReportParameter Name="in_sprache">
<DataType>String</DataType>
<DefaultValue>
<Values>
<Value>de</Value>
</Values>
</DefaultValue>
<Prompt>in_sprache</Prompt>
<Hidden>true</Hidden>
</ReportParameter>
<ReportParameter Name="in_standort">
<DataType>String</DataType>
<DefaultValue>
<DataSetReference>
<DataSetName>SEL_Standort</DataSetName>
<ValueField>RPT_UID</ValueField>
</DataSetReference>
</DefaultValue>
<Prompt>Standort</Prompt>
<ValidValues>
<DataSetReference>
<DataSetName>SEL_Standort</DataSetName>
<ValueField>RPT_UID</ValueField>
<LabelField>RPT_Name</LabelField>
</DataSetReference>
</ValidValues>
</ReportParameter>
```

and the second file is

Arbitrary XML file (geonames):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<geonames style="MEDIUM">
<totalResultsCount>6987</totalResultsCount>
<geoname>
<name>London</name>
<lat>51.5084152563931</lat>
<lng>-0.125532746315002</lng>
<geonameId>2643743</geonameId>
<countryCode>GB</countryCode>
<countryName>United Kingdom</countryName>

<fcl>P</fcl>
<fcode>PPLC</fcode>
</geoname>
<geoname>
<name>London</name>
<lat>42.983389283</lat>
<lng>-81.233042387</lng>
<geonameId>6058560</geonameId>
<countryCode>CA</countryCode>
<countryName>Canada</countryName>

<fcl>P</fcl>
<fcode>PPL</fcode>
</geoname>
<geoname>
<name>East London</name>
<lat>-33.0152850934643</lat>
<lng>27.9116249084473</lng>
<geonameId>1006984</geonameId>
<countryCode>ZA</countryCode>
<countryName>South Africa</countryName>

<fcl>P</fcl>
<fcode>PPL</fcode>
</geoname>
<geoname>
<name>City</name>
<lat>51.5133363996235</lat>
<lng>-0.0890064239501953</lng>
<geonameId>2643744</geonameId>
<countryCode>GB</countryCode>
<countryName>United Kingdom</countryName>

<fcl>A</fcl>
<fcode>ADM2</fcode>
</geoname>
<geoname>
<name>London</name>
<lat>37.1289771</lat>
<lng>-84.0832646</lng>
<geonameId>4298960</geonameId>
<countryCode>US</countryCode>
<countryName>United States</countryName>

<fcl>P</fcl>
<fcode>PPL</fcode>
</geoname>
<geoname>
<name>The Tower of London</name>
<lat>51.5082349601834</lat>
<lng>-0.0763034820556641</lng>
<geonameId>6286786</geonameId>
<countryCode>GB</countryCode>
<countryName>United Kingdom</countryName>

<fcl>S</fcl>
<fcode>CSTL</fcode>
</geoname>
<geoname>
<name>London Reefs</name>
<lat>8.85</lat>
<lng>112.5333333</lng>
<geonameId>1879967</geonameId>
<countryCode>  </countryCode>
<countryName>  </countryName>

<fcl>U</fcl>
<fcode>RFSU</fcode>
</geoname>
<geoname>
<name>Greater London</name>
<lat>51.5</lat>
<lng>-0.1666667</lng>
<geonameId>2648110</geonameId>
<countryCode>GB</countryCode>
<countryName>United Kingdom</countryName>

<fcl>A</fcl>
<fcode>ADM2</fcode>
</geoname>
<geoname>
<name>London</name>
<lat>46.1666667</lat>
<lng>6.0166667</lng>
<geonameId>2661811</geonameId>
<countryCode>CH</countryCode>
<countryName>Switzerland</countryName>

<fcl>H</fcl>
<fcode>STM</fcode>
</geoname>
<geoname>
<name>London Borough of Islington</name>
<lat>51.5333333</lat>
<lng>-0.1333333</lng>
<geonameId>3333156</geonameId>
<countryCode>GB</countryCode>
<countryName>United Kingdom</countryName>

<fcl>A</fcl>
<fcode>ADM2</fcode>
</geoname>
</geonames>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespaces are defined with the special `xmlns` "attribute". There are two namespaces defined on the root element, one of them declares its prefix (`rd`), the other does not. The latter is the default namespace for all the descendants of the node, if not declared otherwise.

Comment: Ah, and because Report is the root element, this is inherited down to the descendants, unless otherwise stated. And on geonames it works, because it doesn't have any xmlns attribute. This clarified it. If xmlns but no prefix, prefix = dft.